# how to solve quadratic homogeneous equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis

How to solve quadratic homogeneous equations(may not have quadratic terms) over a polynomial ring of multiple variables in a field

Comment: Single equation or system of equations?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: you use algebra

Comment: ,Thanks for your attention!I want to solve question about system of equations@Wuestenfux